# the sound of chewing/the implied agent of a gerund

Tags: meaning, gerunds

a. She hates the sound of chewing chips.

Is it clear who is chewing the chips? Is it necessarily 'she' or could it be someone else?

Many thanks

Comment: The person in question strongly dislikes the noise that is produced when someone chews or eats chips

Comment: Teeth! The answer to the riddle is teeth!

Answer (score 1):

*She hates the sound of chewing chips.*

That sounds as if the chips are doing the chewing, and it doesn't make sense.

If you want to omit who is doing the chewing, it could be said:
*She hates the sound of chips being chewed.*

You could also use a generic subject:
*She hates the sound of someone/anyone chewing chips.*

Answer (score 0):

> a. She hates the sound of chewing chips.

The sentence does not say or imply who is chewing the chips.

I would normally interpret it as someone else chewing; why would she still hate that sound if she chooses to chew the chips?

If she is the one making the sound and feels bad, then we could say

> She **feels bad** for making the sound chewing chips.